# Simple Web Agent - Volttron

Tags: python-3.x, raspbian, volttron

I am attempting to launch the Simple Web Agent on the the develop branch using python3 and after having followed the documentation the agent is reportedly running according to "vctl status". However, netstat does not show any process running on the localhost and any attempt to communicate with localhost leads to "localhost refused to connect". Is there some process that must be completed before the documentation (other than activating the platform), or is there some other issue potentially in implementation, or is this a bug.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxNyt.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SimpleWebAgent runs on top of the volttron platform itself.  So you would need to setup the configuration file to support the web itself in the base platform.

```
# bootstrap the environment
(volttron) ~/volttron: python3 bootstrap.py --web

# create instance capable of handling web 
(volttron) ~/volttron: vcfg 

# Start volttron
(volttron) ~/volttron: ./start-volttron
```

Now you can do your netstat test and go from there.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I ended up finding this webpage (https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devguides/walkthroughs/VOLTTRON-Central-Demo.html#volttron-central-demo) which was very helpful. I'm sure that I should have known to look at it but as someone new to the platform it wasn't clear that that was necessary. Thanks again!